# SQLite.NET Performance Using SQLiteParameter with LIKE operator

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-4.1, system.data.sqlite

I am having an issue using SQLiteParameters and the LIKE operator in a SQLite query.  Here is a snippet of code, and I apologize if I don't have enough code here.  If that is the case, I can easily post more.

Poor Performance:

```
using (OdysseyDataContext entities = new OdysseyDataContext())
{
    var results = entities.SearchResults.SqlQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM SearchResults WHERE ContactName LIKE @ContactName",
        new SQLiteParameter("@ContactName", "test")
    );
}
```

Great Performance:

```
using (OdysseyDataContext entities = new OdysseyDataContext())
{
    var results = entities.SearchResults.SqlQuery(
        string.Format(
            "SELECT * FROM SearchResults WHERE ContactName LIKE '{0}'",
            "test"
        )
    );
}
```

Other important code:

```
public class OdysseyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SearchResult> SearchResults { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

The first example takes 700 ms to execute, which my supervisor finds unacceptable.  The second example takes 7 ms to execute.  Why the difference?  Is there something I am doing completely wrong to earn me newbie status?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running multiple tests to eliminate caching artefacts? Do they both return the same rows? Are you using wildcards?

Comment: Also, in implementations of SQLite where the LIKE function is overridden, indexes are unavailable. What do you get with ...where contactname GLOB @contactname  [case sensitive, BTW] ?

Comment: Hi Tim.  Yeah, I'm running multiple tests.  The first time is a little over 1 second and the average over 15 tests is about 700 ms.  Yes, they return the same rows.  No, I'm not using any wild cards.  I know it seems strange, but I'm using the like statement to remove the case sensitive searching so it will use my index setup on ContactName COLLATE NOCASE.

Comment: In your "great performance" query, you're missing a closing double-quote. Doubt that has anything to do with your issue, but just thought I'd bring it up.

Comment: Can we see the `SqlQuery` method source? Are you sure it's the query itself you are timing; or is it including the overhead of creating a parameter and adding it to the collection? (It should be almost no overhead, but we won't know till we see the method's source)

Comment: @vcsjones The SqlQuery method is actually provided by Entity Framework 4.1 on any DbSet<> type.  My apologies for not including the construction of the `entities` item.  I will modify the post to include all those necessary parts.

Comment: I have revised the code above to include any necessary parts, as far as I can tell.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you have a performance-monitor, that can meassure the time needed for your tests. I think that there must be something within the code itself, since the generated queries should be identical- but who knows... If the performance-monitor shows that you really lose the time during the database operation, you know it's not your code and you can focus on the query itself when executed onto your database

Comment: @Gambrinus I just reduced the code to using System.Data.SQLite and executed both of the above queries 10 times.  The poor performance query took an average of 642 ms and the Good performance took an average of 5 ms.  I can post the code if required, but I think that this test I just did reduces it to either System.Data.SQLite or sqlite itself.  Either way, I'm just hoping there is a way to work around this.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think I may have narrowed it down to an issue with System.Data.SQLite.  I tried the following code in C++:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void xProfile(void* pArg, const char* query, sqlite3_uint64 pTimeTaken)
{
    printf("%s\n", query);
    printf("%I64d ms\n", pTimeTaken / 1000000);
}

void PoorPerformance();
void GoodPerformance();

int main()
{
    printf("Poor Performance:\n");
    PoorPerformance();

    printf("Good Performance:\n");
    GoodPerformance();

    return 0;
}

void PoorPerformance()
{
    int rc;
    int rowCount = 0;

    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open("<<File Here>>", &db))
    {
        printf("Could not open the database.");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_profile(db, &xProfile, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (!sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM SearchResults WHERE ContactName LIKE @ContactName;", -1, &statement, 0))
    {
        int result = 0;
        int parameterIndex = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statement, "@ContactName");
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "test", -1, NULL);
        while (result != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            result = sqlite3_step(statement);

            if (result == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                rowCount++;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    printf("%d rows\n", rowCount);

    sqlite3_close(db);
}

void GoodPerformance()
{
    int rc;
    int rowCount = 0;

    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open("<<File Here>>", &db))
    {
        printf("Could not open the database.");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_profile(db, &xProfile, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (!sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM SearchResults WHERE ContactName LIKE 'test';", -1, &statement, 0))
    {
        int result = 0;

        while (result != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            result = sqlite3_step(statement);

            if (result == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                rowCount++;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    printf("%d rows\n", rowCount);

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Both the PoorPerformance and GoodPerformance functions yielded 1 ms with 11 rows.  Is there something different between what I did and what should have been done by System.Data.SQLite?  Hopefully this is just something I can report as a bug with System.Data.SQLite and perhaps apply my own fix.

Comment: Do you have any update on your issue with System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: @Shrike Check out my reply below.. it may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot see any difference between the two queries, but the fact, that one uses sqliteparameter and the other one a complete sql-statement as string - I just googled your problem and stumbled upon [that](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/parameters.html#perfissues).

There it indicates that on the SQLiteCommand object there is a property called [ParameterCheck](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand_members.html), which can cause some performance loss.

You could try to rewrite your code to pass a SQLiteCommand object and set the ParameterCheck property to false. I think you should gain some speed doing this.

At least it's worth a shot :)

Comment: I was so hoping that this would solve my problem!  Unfortunately this uses Devart.Data.SQLite rather than System.Data.SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had performance issues with System.Data.SQLite, some of which I have been able to address and improve, and others I have not.

However, recently I discovered this alternative C# SQLite library: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

It has given me no performance issues, and I actually replaced System.Data.SQLite with this one in an existing project (almost no changes in syntax - I more or less literally just replaced the DLL and the using directive.. there were a couple lines where I had to typecast something), and it sped things up marvelously. There were times where I was waiting on the order of seconds with System.Data.SQLite, and now the executions are instantaneous.